# Checking Color of a Cell and Returning a Color to another Cell

Tags: excel, colors

I need to check if A1 is red and if it is true, then need to make A2 red.

Would appreciate any help.

P.s I have no clue on how to use VBA. Please give me some tips on how to implement this using VBA or any other means if it is possible that is.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that **A1** does not have conditional formats:

```
Sub dural()
    If Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**